# Tmux - ambiguous option: mouse error

Tags: macos, tmux

I recently updated my OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.1) and my tmux (version 1.9a via Homebrew) mouse mode stopped working. I get the error:

`/Users/username/.tmux.conf:57: ambiguous option: mouse`

On line 57 of my `tmux.conf`, I have the following code to enable mouse mode:

`set -g mouse on`

And the the following lines to enable/disable mouse mode:

```
# Toggle mouse on
bind m \
    set -g mouse on \;\
    display 'Mouse: ON'

# Toggle mouse off
bind M \
    set -g mouse off \;\
    display 'Mouse: OFF'

# Start copy mode when scrolling up or down
bind -n WheelUpPane copy-mode
bind -n WheelDownPane copy-mode
```

I previously had to update `mouse-mode` to `mouse` to fix the mouse mode when I updated tmux. I tried reverting that fix with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The new mouse mode (i.e. the one you're activating in your config) became available with tmux 2.1, see the [changelog](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES#L6-L13) for details. Updating to the latest version should resolve your issue.